# Using Rules in Scrapy to crawl specific links

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to scrape airline review data from tripadvisor. First I am extracting all id and corresponding airline name. I am using following code to crawl only the links containing 'Airline_Review'.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

URL = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com'

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
               'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airlines'
               ]

        rules = (
                Rule(
                    LinkExtractor(allow = '.*Airline_Review.*'),
                    callback = 'parse',
                    follow= True
                    )
                )
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
            url= URL + url 

            url = url.strip()
            with open('op.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(url)
                f.write('\n') 

            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

But still I am getting links in my op.txt file that does not contain 'Airline_Review'. What is incorrect in my code?

Comment: Strange. Did you try adding the prefix `r` to the `allow` parameter? Regex strings usually have the prefix `r` in python.

Comment: I tried adding the prefix r, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Can you share the scrapy logs?

Comment: The scrapy log basically does not show any error, it shows all the links that are being crawled by scrapy. The op.txt file contains all kinds of links with and without 'Airline_Review'